# Issues rendering a ggplot in rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, render

I been working on an Rmarkdown document that features tables and charts and all was well but now when trying to insert a ggplot chart it says it cant fetch resource and describes the ggplot as a .png. The code below causes the error for me using these system settings:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] scales_1.2.1    lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    tidyverse_2.0.0 bookdown_0.35   plotly_4.10.2   ggplot2_3.4.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.3            xfun_0.40               htmlwidgets_1.6.2       tzdb_0.4.0              vctrs_0.6.3             tools_4.3.1             generics_0.1.3          curl_5.0.1              fansi_1.0.4            
[10] pkgconfig_2.0.3         data.table_1.14.8       uuid_1.1-0              lifecycle_1.0.3         flextable_0.9.2         farver_2.1.1            compiler_4.3.1          textshaping_0.3.6       munsell_0.5.0          
[19] httpuv_1.6.11           fontquiver_0.2.1        fontLiberation_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.5         yaml_2.3.7              lazyeval_0.2.2          later_1.3.1             pillar_1.9.0            crayon_1.5.2           
[28] gfonts_0.2.0            ellipsis_0.3.2          openssl_2.1.0           mime_0.12               fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 tidyselect_1.2.0        zip_2.3.0               digest_0.6.33           stringi_1.7.12         
[37] labeling_0.4.2          fastmap_1.1.1           grid_4.3.1              colorspace_2.1-0        cli_3.6.1               magrittr_2.0.3          crul_1.4.0              utf8_1.2.3              withr_2.5.0            
[46] gdtools_0.3.3           promises_1.2.0.1        timechange_0.2.0        rmarkdown_2.23          officer_0.6.2           httr_1.4.6              hms_1.1.3               askpass_1.1             ragg_1.2.5             
[55] shiny_1.7.4.1           evaluate_0.21           knitr_1.43              viridisLite_0.4.2       rlang_1.1.1             Rcpp_1.0.11             xtable_1.8-4            glue_1.6.2              httpcode_0.3.0         
[64] xml2_1.3.5              rstudioapi_0.15.0       jsonlite_1.8.7          R6_2.5.1                systemfonts_1.0.4
```

This is my rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Test" 
author: |
  | Author: Author Name
  | Unit: Unit
  | Email: email address
  | Github Handle: handle
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
      fig_caption: TRUE
      toc: true
      toc_depth: 3
      toc_float: true
      number_sections: true
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { 
      out_dir <- '../Reports/';
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding, 
                        output_file=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir, "GGPLOT_TEST.html")) })

link-citations: true
bibliographystyle: apalike
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  #echo = FALSE,
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  root.dir = "f:/Crash Analysis/Vehicle_Design_and_Injury_Severity/"
)
.libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/library")
#library(xfun)
library(bookdown)
library(tidyverse)  #For data wrangling
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plotly)
    
### test chart below

```{r echo = T,include = T, ggplot}    
    
    dat = mtcars
    #Make chart
    ##################################
    #Prepare data

    p = ggplot( dat, aes(x = mpg, y =wt)) +
        geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y =wt)) + 
        geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y =wt)) +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +     
        theme(text = element_text(size = 16)) +
        guides(color=guide_legend(title="Body Type"))
    
    print(p)
```
````

And here is the error

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource http://wpdotfill09/R_VMP3_USERS/tdb069/Crash%20Analysis/Vehicle_Design_and_Injury_Severity/Reports/GGPLOT_TEST_files/figure-html/ggplot-1.png: HttpExceptionRequest Request {
    host                 = "wpdotfill09"
    port                 = 80
    secure               = False
    requestHeaders       = []
    path                 = "/R_VMP3_USERS/tdb069/Crash%20Analysis/Vehicle_Design_and_Injury_Severity/Reports/GGPLOT_TEST_files/figure-html/ggplot-1.png"
    queryString          = ""
    method               = "GET"
    proxy                = Nothing
    rawBody              = False
    redirectCount        = 10
    responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
    requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
    proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect
  }
   (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 792>: failed (Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED)))

Output created: ../Reports//GGPLOT_TEST.html
```

I am on a network drive but i have had r markdowns working before on network drive so really not sure what is going on.  If i use plotly::ggplotly the figure renders which further perplexes me.  What am i missing?

Comment: I personally will do everything I can to _not_ render a document (finale or temp-files) on a network share, but most of this caution is borne from working on Windows and some of its "net directory-mount woes". They generally work, but they aren't 100% the same, and problems can be difficult to nail down. For that reason, perhaps even when I don't need to, I do all rendering in a temporary local filesystem before moving finished results to the desired directory.

Comment: Perhaps not a surprise, when rendering this on a local filesystem (on linux), the document renders without error. I believe the error is caused by the filesystem difference. Are you able to try this completely on a local drive to see if you can reproduce it there?

Comment: I did just move the project with the current problem to a c:/ drive and it worked so when in doubt this is a good solution but our agency will not allow me to work off C:/ this drive long term  so will need longer term solution.  Weird thing is set up this markdown based on one that worked and in fact still works is one thing thats made debugging harder.  I started with [this previous](https://rpubs.com/ODOT_Research/Ped_Traffic_Liquidation_Costs) as my base and it works in the same R Studio environment.  Works when i moved it to C: but my other ones still work. Can work on C:/ long term tho

Comment: I understand some companies lock down `C:/`, though it _cannot_ be absolute, there are some things that must really (for practical reasons if not theoretical) allow some local use. Try seeing if you can write to `Sys.getenv("TEMP")` or `Sys.getenv("TMP")` (assuming `C:/`); similarly see if `c:/Users/yourusername/AppData/Local` is writable. For any/all of those, if you find a location to which you have "full-enough" write-permissions, try using that for all intermediate document rendering.